# Grouping issue with SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I am building a very basic level Event management & Invitation system. For that I have build 2 tables and using a query to list all events with their Invitation counts as 
1. Total Invitations Sent
2. Total Accepted
3. Total Rejected
4. Total Waiting

Below is the query

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    count(im.event_id_fk) as total_invitations, 
    count(im2.event_id_fk) as total_accepted, 
    count(im3.event_id_fk) as total_rejected,
    count(im4.event_id_fk) as total_waiting 
FROM event_mst em
LEFT JOIN invitation_mst im
    ON (em.event_id_pk = im.event_id_fk)
LEFT JOIN invitation_mst im2
    ON (em.event_id_pk = im2.event_id_fk AND im2.status = 'Accept')
LEFT JOIN invitation_mst im3
    ON (em.event_id_pk = im3.event_id_fk AND im3.status = 'Reject')
LEFT JOIN invitation_mst im4
    ON (em.event_id_pk = im4.event_id_fk AND im4.status = 'Waiting')
GROUP BY 
    im.event_id_fk, 
    im2.event_id_fk, 
    im3.event_id_fk, 
    im4.event_id_fk 
ORDER BY 
    em.date_added DESC
```

Now the issue is that this query is giving Wrong counts, e.g. if there are total 3 Invitations sent, it is giving 9. If there are 5 invitations sent, it is giving 25.

so it seems that it is multiplying with itself and returning the result. I know there must be something wrong with this select query. Anyone correct me this query ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simpliest solution for mysql because it supports boolean calculation.

```
SELECT  event_id_pk,
        COUNT(*) as total_invitations, 
        SUM(status = 'Accept') as total_accepted, 
        SUM(status = 'Reject') as total_rejected,
        SUM(status = 'Waiting') as total_waiting 
FROM    event_mst
GROUP   BY event_id_pk
```

but the query will not give you full details on the invitation, in order to do that, you can wrap the query in the subquery and join that with the original table itself,

```
SELECT  a.*,
        b.total_invitations,
        b.total_rejected,
        b.total_waiting
FROM    event_mst a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  event_id_pk,
                    COUNT(*) as total_invitations, 
                    SUM(status = 'Accept') as total_accepted, 
                    SUM(status = 'Reject') as total_rejected,
                    SUM(status = 'Waiting') as total_waiting 
            FROM    event_mst
            GROUP   BY event_id_pk
        ) b ON a.event_id_pk = b.event_id_pk
```

Comment: Thanks, finally it leaded me to this query

SELECT *, 
count(im.event_id_fk) as total_invitations, 
SUM(im.status = 'Accept') as total_accepted, 
SUM(im.status = 'Reject') as total_rejected,
SUM(im.status = 'Waiting') as total_waiting 
FROM event_mst em
LEFT JOIN invitation_mst im
ON (em.event_id_pk=im.event_id_fk)
GROUP BY im.event_id_fk 
ORDER BY em.date_added DESC